# Perpetual motion

Tags: gravity-assist

When I was young, I had a set of bar magnets which had poles on the side faces (across the thickness) and not at the two ends. I placed one on the table facing one pole upwards (say north pole). Accidently though, the second magnet slipped from my hand, and one end got stuck in some irregularity on the table. I noticed that the other end of the magnet started falling down towards the first magnet, and just before touching the same, it was thrown back upwards. Certainly the north pole of second magnet was facing down and was "repelled" by the one on the table. This continued for a long time.

My question is, if we construct some device with zero friction, can this movement be close to perpetual motion? We are actually using "gravitational force" to achieve this movement, but this gravity is constant and never ending. Can this be used for any kind of useful work?

Comment: Can it be close? yes of course, but its impossible to create any kind of device with zero friction. When it comes to extracting work from the system, this is of course impossible, as that would violate the 1st law of thermodynamics. I don't see how this is a question for the space exploration stack exchange though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems more like a physics question than anything to do with space exploration

Comment: Any time you have a moving magnetic field you will have losses as heat from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current, so general any magnetic perpetual motion question ends up there.

Comment: Alexander and Steve, I am sorry if I have caused any inconvenience with my question. I agree that this is not a space exploration related question. In fact, I now realize that this particular site is about "SPACE" and related things. It was out of scientific curiosity that I posted this question here. Would you like to suggest any site where I can post my questions?

Answer (score 2):

No not really because any kind of electrical generation that could be made from this would introduce friction into the system or at least some resistance, and therefore it would eventually stop. At our current level of knowledge perpetual motion is impossible as there is no such thing as zero resistance.